# Nginx Proxy for github.io is returning 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, github-pages

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse-proxy for my pages at github pages. Based on info from here: https://pascal.io/github-pages-https/, and others, my config looks like this:

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
    server_name leepope.com www.leepope.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name leepope.com;


  ssl                 on;
  ssl_certificate     <my cert>;
  ssl_certificate_key <my key>;
  ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

  ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;


  location / {
    proxy_pass              https://leepope.github.io;
    proxy_set_header        Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    expires                 off;
  } 
}
```

When I make a request to the server root, I get a github page, but it's a 404.

I've enabled nginx debugging, but I can't see what the request going to github looks like - their headers are in the log, but there's no info about what's going out.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to disable https on the backend with: `proxy_pass http://leepope.github.io;`

Comment: Replace `$host` with `"leepope.github.io"` on your `proxy_set_header` line.